# How to easily do the DAG analyse of a pipeline?

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, snakemake

To optimize a pipeline, it's important to know the rate-limiting rules or paths. Based on the DAG analyse, is there any approaches that could easily calculate the critical path or the key events ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question to answer, but you may be interested in looking at the [`--runtime-profile`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html) command line argument, which can be used to profile Snakemake code using [yappi](https://github.com/sumerc/yappi).